# Работа с std::wifstream и std::wofstream. С++

Tags: c++, файлы, unicode, fstream

Есть такая структура:

```
typedef struct someStruct
{
    wchar_t name[10];
    wchar_t name[30];
    wchar_t middle_name[30];
    int year_of_birth;
    int day_of_birth;


} MYSTRUCT
```

и есть функция для чтения из файла и записи в файл - все в бинарном виде.

```
MYSTRUCT ReadFromFile(string fileName)
{
    MYSTRUCT myStruct;
    wifstream in(fileName);
    in.read((wchar_t*)&myStruct, sizeof(MYSTRUCT));
    in.close();
    return myStruct;
}

void SaveToFile(MYSTRUCT myStruct)
{
    wofstream out(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
    out.write((wchar_t*)&myStruct, sizeof(MYSTRUCT));
    out.close();
}
```

Не знаю в чем проблема, но корректной записи и чтения не происходит.
P.S. Если использовать ofstream | ifstream вместо wifstream и wofstream, то все работает. Но нужна поддержка unicode.

Comment: Какая еще поддержка юникода (которую wofstream вообще-то не толком не добавляет), если файл открывается в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @user7860670 ну вот на метаните вычитал, что при работе с wchar_t нужно использовать https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/8.2.php

Comment: Так вы тут не с wchar работаете, а со структурой.

Comment: @Genjutsu то есть не обращать внимания на то, что в структуре есть wchar_t и делать через ifstream и ofstream соответственно?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP да. Читайте байты (unsigned char, он же std::byte), пишите тоже байты